# Any user interface (UI) for BIND dns server?

Tags: gui, dns

I am looking for a UI solution to sit on top of a BIND dns server implementation.

We want to avoid changing zones by hand. I have found some APIs that utilize rndc and nsupdate but only few of themhave a UI, but they are a bit obsolete.

Comment: Do you want a standalone GUI? Or a web UI?

Comment: I would prefer a web UI, but any lead would be appreciated.